# Why doesn't react update the states immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-router

As the title says, I'm having issues with the logic of the code I wrote, it should exactly follow this pattern to authenticate a user based on the input values below:

Firstly, when the user clicks on the `login` button after typing in both inputs, it will call the `handleAuth` function which will take in `username` and `password` from the respective states, and then that function `(loginCheck)` will check if the user is found and matches the conditions I set in that line in, and then going to return the whole user data back to `handleAuth` function again, calling the last function that will navigate the user to respective pages, which are home page, in case the user is not authorized because of `isLogged` state is not and `currentUser` state is either `null` or `undefined`, or if he is authorized, and is, therefore, `currentUser` state is `truthy` and the user is found, he will be redirected to profile page, sending a username props along with..so far so good, yeah

But the thing is, it will only redirect me to the `profile` page when I click on the button `twice`,  which makes the login look weird, it's obvious that I'm skipping a super important rule but can't figure it out now, feeling so stuck with that issue, any kind of help is appreciated, thanks...

I also tried replacing all functions with useEffect so it would have render only when the states get an update based on dependency arrays, but in that case i cant reach out to functions, shall i stick to useRef instead of the states?

Here you can also check the latest case live:

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mendel-syxlol?file=/src/index.js
```

```js
import { Route, Routes, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react'
import {useMemo} from  'react';

function App() {

 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({id:null, username:null, password:null});
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
const [passInput, setPassInput] = useState("");
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const data = [
    { id: 1, username: "jane", password: "1234",isAdmin:true },
    { id: 2, username: "jack", password: "1234", isAdmin: false },
    { id: 3, username: "john", password: "1234" , isAdmin:false},
    { id: 4, username: "elizabeth", password: "1234", isAdmin: false}
  ];

  
  
  const loginCheck = (username, password) => {
  
    console.log("logincheck function working");
    const userData = (userid,userpass) => data.find(user => user.username === userid && user.password === userpass);  
     
       const getUserData = userData(username,password);
       console.log(getUserData)
     
       if(getUserData){
          
     console.log(`${getUserData.username} logged in`)
     return getUserData;
   
       }
       else if (getUserData===null || getUserData===undefined){
        
         console.log("user not found")
         return null
       }
       else
       {
         console.log("an error occured")
       }
     
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
   };

const handleAuth = () => {

console.log("handlesubmit function working");
const gelen = loginCheck(userInput, passInput);

if (gelen  !== null || gelen !== undefined) {

 setIsLogged(true);
 setCurrentUser({id:gelen?.id, username:gelen?.username, password:gelen?.password});
 navigateAfterLogin();

}
else
{
setIsLogged(false);
setCurrentUser({...currentUser});
navigateAfterLogin();

}

}

const navigateAfterLogin = () => {
  console.log("navigation function working.");

  if (isLogged){
    if (currentUser.id && currentUser.username && currentUser.password) {
      console.log("redirecting to profile page");

      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    navigate(`/users/${currentUser.username}`,
     {state: {id:currentUser.id, 
      username:currentUser.username,
     isAdmin:currentUser.isAdmin}});
      }, 3000);

      
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);

  }
}
  else {
    if (!currentUser.id && !currentUser.username && !currentUser.password) {
      console.log("redirecting to login page");
      navigate(`/login`);
    }
  
  }
};

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="login">Login</Link>
      <input name = "username" type = "text"  placeholder = "username" onChange={(e)=> setUserInput(e.target.value)}  /> 
      <input name = "password" type = "password"  placeholder = "password" onChange={(e)=> setPassInput(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick = {handleAuth} type = "submit">Login</button>
<div style = {{display:"flex",flexDirection:"column",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
  <h1>
<label>hesabınıza giriş yapın</label>

  </h1>
</div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="users/:id" element={<Profile/>} />
          
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 not found</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Don't make `isLogged` and `currentUser` states. Make them parameters of `navigateAfterLogin` and pass them directly - you're not using them anywhere else anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, calling `navigateAfterLogin` only from an effect that depends on the `isLogged`/`currentUser` states should have worked as well

Comment: ok never mind, fixed it now, thanks anyway, useeffect works perfectly !